# How to Google calendar api connect Mysql

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

Please tell me Can the Google Calendar api connect to the database? If so, how?  **create for applications

Answer (score 1):

Yes, google API can connect to a database with some work.

You can find more information here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview

It would be easier to create an application that interacts with the database and the google calendar through the API's provided.

That site will also give you a nice starting point for your application in the language you choose.